# Restricted to CSS-2.1, can I ensure that one border in a table shows 'on top' of another border when borders are collapsed

Tags: html, css, border

Pictures are worth much more than words, in this case.  See how the intersection of the top, black bar and the lightgrey, vertical bar between 'Left' and 'Right' is lightgrey instead of black?  Is there a way to ensure that one border is shown 'above' another, kind of like a z-index?

How it looks:

[image: table]

How I want it to look (adjusted with image editor):

[image]

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgsk6ru3/1/) for my issue.  If you don't like jsfiddle, for whatever reason, my HTML and CSS are below.

HTML:

```
<table id="tiresTable" class="table">
<tr class="firstRow">
    <td class="thSim">Tires:</td>
    <td class="thXAxis borderRight">Left</td>
    <td class="thXAxis">Right</td>
</tr>
<tr class="borderBottom">
    <td class="thYAxis">Front</td>
    <td class="borderRight"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="borderBottom">
    <td class="thYAxis">Rear</td>
    <td class="borderRight"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="thYAxis">Spare</td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#tiresTable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tiresTable tr.firstRow td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#tiresTable td.thSim, #tiresTable td.thYAxis{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#tiresTable td.borderRight{
    border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
#tiresTable tr.borderBottom{
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

Please note that, due to technological constraints, I cannot use CSS3 properties.  Also note that I will not be offended if you edit my question title if you can describe the issue more eloquently than I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It was a little hacky but I was able to do something that works as you need.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tiresTable" class="table">
<tr class="firstRow">
    <td class="thSim">Tires:</td>
    <td class="thXAxis borderRight">Left</td>
    <td class="thXAxis">Right</td>
</tr>
    <tr class="border-bottom">
        <td colspan="3"><div class="black"></div></td>
    </tr>
<tr class="borderBottom">
    <td class="thYAxis">Front</td>
    <td class="borderRight"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="borderBottom">
    <td class="thYAxis">Rear</td>
    <td class="borderRight"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="thYAxis">Spare</td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tiresTable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tiresTable tr.borderBottom{
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
#tiresTable td.borderRight{
    border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

#tiresTable td.thSim, #tiresTable td.thYAxis{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.border-bottom {
    height: 1px;
}

.border-bottom td {
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.black {
    background-color: black;
    height: 1px;
}
```

I removed anything that is not really required, and used altered classes names to know easily what is new and what is not.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ru92py4m/15/

Comment: But I don't want that border line in the header to be black (the vertical line between 'Left' and 'Right'.  That part should be lightgrey, but the point where it intersects with the black horizontal line should be black.

Comment: Now there isn't a top horizontal line.

Comment: That's pretty clever.  I don't know if there is a more 'legit' way of doing this, but I like this trick.

Comment: I found that your problem was ocurring because of how the border works. Very often I find myself trying to solve a problem that I'm fiding with some CSS that's not working how I'm wanting to, so, as long as it doesn't consume too much processing, I think fair enough. I'm the same position as you, that's why I only found this solution.